# Infinite structures - closed under ultraproducts but not closed under elementary equivalence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I just want to make sure that class of infinite structures is a good example of class of structures closed under ultraproducts but not under elementary equivalence.

The first one is obvious, whereas the second one holds because we can add infinite number of constants to a finite structure, and using compactness theorem get a new infinite structure which will be elementary equivalent to the finite one.
Is it ok example?

Comment: How about the uncountable structures, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. It's hard to pin down exactly where it breaks since you haven't really given details about how you're applying compactness here, but in fact the class of infinite structures **is** closed under elementary equivalence. This is because for each finite $n$ there is a sentence $\varphi_n$ which is true in exactly the structures of size $\ge n$; if $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite and $\mathcal{B}$ is finite, then we have $$\mathcal{A}\models\varphi_{\vert\mathcal{B}\vert+1}\quad\mbox{but}\quad\mathcal{B}\not\models\varphi_{\vert\mathcal{B}\vert+1}.$$

Namely, $\varphi_n$ is the sentence $$\exists x_1,...,x_n(\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}x_i\not=x_j).$$

---

Instead, we need to use the (downwards) Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. You've correctly observed that the class $C_\kappa$ of structures of cardinality $\ge\kappa$ is always closed under ultraproducts, and so we're looking for something which can "shrink" structures while preserving elementary equivalence. This (with $\kappa=\aleph_0$) is what you've tried to use compactness to do, but that didn't work. Instead, use downwards Lowenheim-Skolem (with $\kappa=\aleph_1$ - but $\aleph_{\omega^2+17}$, or indeed *any* uncountable $\kappa$, would also work): the class $\mathbb{U}$ of uncountable structures is trivially closed under ultraproducts, but by downwards Lowenheim-Skolem for each $M\in \mathbb{U}$ there is a countable (hence $\not\in \mathbb{U}$) structure $N$ with $M\equiv N$, so $\mathbb{U}$ is not closed under elementary equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will think more about example of such situation.

Comment: @MaciejFicek As a suggestion, note that you've already observed that ultraproducts never decrease cardinality - that is, the class of structures of size $\ge\kappa$ is always closed under ultraproducts for any cardinal $\kappa$. This suggests that you look for a way to "shrink" the cardinality of a structure while preserving elementary equivalence. You've tried this here - with $\kappa=\aleph_0$, and using compactness - but it hasn't worked; can you think of some result which lets you "shrink" structures (and what the corresponding $\kappa$ should be)?

Comment: I think that result can be downward Skolem-Lowenheim theorem, right?

Comment: @MaciejFicek Exactly - so what class of structures does that suggest? (Incidentally, an unrelated pet peeve of mine: the *upward* Lowenheim-Skolem theorem is really just a trivial corollary of compactness; it's the *downward* Lowenheim-Skolem theorem that's really deep and different.)

Comment: So, the class of structures of cardinality for example aleph one is closed under ultraproducts, but not under elementary equivalence bcs there are structures of cardinality aleph zero equivalent.

Comment: @MaciejFicek That's exactly right. (And I've edited that into the answer.)

Comment: "the class of structures of cardinality for example aleph one" - I think it is false if you want to define your class to consist of models of cardinality **exactly** $\aleph_1$, since if the ultrafilter you're using for the ultraproduct construction is not $\sigma$-complete, then the ultraproduct of a sequence of infinite models will be always of cardinality at least continuum, so e.g. assuming $\neg CH$, your class will no longer be closed under ultraproducts. You have to take  what Noah called above the class $C_\kappa$ of structures of size **at least** $\kappa$, for $\kappa$ uncountable.

Comment: @MaciejFicek mtg is absolutely right - I misread your "of cardinality aleph one" as "of cardinality *at least* aleph one."

Comment: @mtg Good catch.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was thinking Hood yesterday but wrote exactly not at least. Thanks